# syntax error near unexpected token do in bash-script

Tags: bash, git-bash, calabash, bash-completion

While I am running such scripit it throughs me an error

```
xargs -a /root/magicparameter/ssrf.txt -I@ bash -c ‘for url in $(cat FUZZvul.txt); do echo “$url&@=http://g8p1iuccym91pvte3ek581o8szypme.burpcollaborator.net”;done’ | httpx -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Error

```
unexpected token 'do' (position 83)
```

Comment: The `-c` argument needs to be surrounded by normal single quotes, not curly quotes. Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: xargs -a /root/magicparameter/ssrf.txt -I@ bash -c 'for url in $(cat FUZZvul.txt); do echo “$url&@=http://g8p1iuccym91pvte3ek581o8szypme.burpcollaborator.net”;done' | httpx -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Now check out this command is this ok

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.